# ¿Por qué obtengo este error en C# a la hora de querer imprimir por pantalla? Invalid expresion term

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace ConceptosPOO
{
    class Punto
    {
        public Punto(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Coordenada x: {x},
            Coordenada y: {y}");
        }
    }
}
```

Archivo con la clase Punto:

```
using System;

namespace ConceptosPoo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void realizarTarea()
    {
        Punto origen = new Punto(34,2); 
    }

}
```

Estoy intentando imprimir por pantalla las coordenadas declaradas en el segundo archivo, 34 y 2, pero me devuelve un error tanto la clase Punto como el Console.WriteLine(). Primero he creado una función static void para crear el objeto origen a partir de la clase punto. Luego le he pasado los valores pero obtengo el error.

Comment: Buenas, `Console.WriteLine($"Coordenada x: {x}, Coordenada y: {y}");` debe ir en una línea, por el resto a mí me va bien tu código.

Comment: Además tendrás que llamar al método `realizarTarea()` para que haga algo el código

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente el error es porque la función/metodo *realizarTarea()* se encuentra fuera de la clase Program
Deberia ser asi la jerarquia

- -namespace ConceptosPoo
- ---class Program
- -------static void Main
- -------static void realizarTarea

Pero ademas como te comentan falta llamar al metodo *realizarTarea()* en la *Main()*

El codigo quedaria algo asi

```
namespace ConceptosPoo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            realizarTarea(); 
        }

        static void realizarTarea()
        {
            Punto origen = new Punto(34,2); 
        }

    }

 }
```

Mira el código funcionando online https://dotnetfiddle.net/oR0jj5 (Aquí coloque la clase Punto dentro de clase Program pero tu lo tienes separado en otro archivo sobre el mismo namespaces)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía